# TextInputLayout - make it clickable with working ripple effect

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I want that my `TextInputLayout` has following functions:

- open a dialog on click
- show a ripple background like e.g. the `ExposedDropdownMenu` style does

It should look like a `TextInputLayout` but work like a `Button`.

**Code**

What I have so far is following:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilPlannedStartTime"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/planned_start_time"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tielPlannedStartTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And following:

```
binding.actvPlannedStartTime.setText(workout.item.plannedStartTime?.toString(SimpleTime.Format.DisplayHM) ?: "-")
    binding.tielPlannedStartTime.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(it.context, "TIEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.tilPlannedStartTime.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(it.context, "TIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

**Problem**

The click event does not have any visual feedback (ripple) like e.g. the `ExposedDropdownMenu` style would have. Any ideas how to solve this better?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but this will remove your current background (so probably also frame around `EditText`). some workaround may be to wrap your lines in `FrameLayout`, make it clickable (`OnClickListener` for it) and with attr `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` (`foreground` is available only for `FrameLayout`, `TextInputLayout` extends `LinearLayout` sadly and don't have foreground...)

Comment: better than nothing, but this apparently won't create a clipped ripple effect inside the borders of `TextInputLayout` like the `ExposedDropdownMenu` does it e.g.

Comment: well, as `TextInputLayout` doesn't have own ripple effect set you may create own custom ripple effect with mask similar to borders of `TextInputLayout`, some example [HERE](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-2/). afaik there is no way for getting "real" border/shape of `TextInputLayout`